# How to split the loop to display 2 items per slide and 1 item every 3rd slide

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have a collection of about a dozen images in the database, let's say 19.

I need to make a foreach loop that will split the entire set by 2 images. So I will have 9 slides of 2 images and the 10th slide will have 1 image.

But every fifth item should display as one.

Example:

slide 1 - 2 images

slide 2 - 2 images

slide 3 - 1 image

slide 4 - 2 images

slide 5 - 2 images

slide 6 - 1 image

and so on.

How can i achieve this?

I got something like this:

```
$n = 0;
foreach($realizations_mobile as $i => $slide) {
    $i = $i + 1;

    echo '<div class="relative float-left -mr-[100%]'; 
    if($i != 1) {
        echo ' hidden';
    } 
    echo ' w-full transition-transform duration-[600ms] ease-in-out motion-reduce:transition-none" data-te-carousel-item'; 
    if($i == 1) {
        echo ' data-te-carousel-active';
    } 
    echo '> <div class="flex flex-col gap-[30px]">';
    $n++;
    foreach($slide as $c => $element) {
        if($i % 3 == 0) {
            echo '1 element<br>';
            echo $element['source'].'<br>';
        } else {
            echo '2 elements<br>';
            echo $element['source'].'<br>';
        }
    }
    if($n == 3) {
        $n = 0;
    }
    echo '</div>
    </div>';
}
```

controller.php:

```
public function realizations_mobile()
{
    $media_gallery = carbon_get_post_meta(88, 'crb_media_gallery_realizations');
    $images_per_slide = 2;

    //define how many slides do we need
    $rest = count($media_gallery) % $images_per_slide;
    $slides_qty = ceil(count($media_gallery) / $images_per_slide);
    
    $slides = [];
    
    //create the right amount of slides and complete with gallery element, or if empty then false
    for($i = 0; $i < $slides_qty * $images_per_slide; $i++) {
        if(empty($media_gallery[$i])) {
            $slides[floor($i / $images_per_slide)][] = [
                'source' => false,
                'number' => $i % $images_per_slide,
            ];
        } else {
            $slides[floor($i / $images_per_slide)][] = [
                'source' => $media_gallery[$i],
                'number' => $i % $images_per_slide,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $slides;
}
```

But I can't make it work as intended

Comment: Could you include what `$realizacje_mobile` is?

Comment: I updated first post, this controller can be rebuild for make this work

Comment: Good code indentation and layout would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code** Did someone tell you unreadable code runs faster?
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Comment: `$i = $i + 1;` So what was `$i` before this line?

Comment: This is only for start counting from 1 not 0

Comment: So initialise it

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep track of the number of items and MOD 5, or number of slides and MOD 3, they are logically equivalent. However, in my mind, "slides" don't really exist, I'm not "making a slide", I'm just changing my output, so I prefer to keep track of items.

```php
$data = range(1, 18);

// You can either index by 0 and add one, or 1 and subtract one
for($i = 1; $i <= count($data); $i++) {
    
    // Variable for easier reference later
    $item = $data[$i - 1];
    
    // On the fifth item, emit logic for just one
    if(0 === $i % 5){
        echo 'Single: ' . $item;
    }else {
        
        // Grab the next if it exsts
        $next = $data[$i++] ?? null;
        if($next){
            echo 'Double: ' . $item . ', ' . $next;
        }else{
            echo 'Double: ' . $item;
        }
    }
    
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```bash
Double: 1, 2
Double: 3, 4
Single: 5
Double: 6, 7
Double: 8, 9
Single: 10
Double: 11, 12
Double: 13, 14
Single: 15
Double: 16, 17
Double: 18
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/LA46Y

Comment: Thank You. It's almost there. :) Now how to do that for slides?

Comment: I was hoping you'd be able to merge this into your code. Your posted code has two `foreach` loops, and unfortunately the variable names aren't in a language I'm familiar with, so it is hard for me to determine what it is really trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your commitment. I tried to adapt your solution but without success. I corrected the code in the first post to make it more readable and in English

Comment: Thanks for that, however I think I'd need to see a dump of what `$realizations_mobile` ultimately holds. That seems to be an array of groups of slides maybe? It does feel like you are fighting this in two spots, both the function `realizations_mobile()` as well as the first block you posted, but I could be wrong on that.